# How to detect a change in Notification (Status bar notification) in Android

Tags: android, android-notifications, notification-listener

I'd tried `NotificationListenerService` provided by Android to listen to notifications by using it's `OnNotificationPosted()` method. That's all okay. How to detect a change in that notification?

**For example**: In WhatsApp, if a message is sent and then deleted, It removes the existing notification and sends a new notification as "This message was deleted".
So how to detect that which notification gets changed or updated?

Answer (score 1):

Are you receiving the "changed" notification in onNotificationPosted()? As far as I understand, the notification is replaced instead of changed. So the changes may register as a newly arrived notification.

Update: it turns out "updating" the notification is indeed pushing a new notification but with the same id. So simply track the id of the notification to see which notification was updated.
In your notification listener onNotificationPosted()

```
 public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)
 {
     //this is the notification id
     int id = sbn.getId();
     ...
 }
```